# What is the best way to develop a mobile application that run on multiple devices mainly (android and iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, android, mobile-application

What is the best way to develop a mobile application that run on multiple devices mainly (android and iPhone)?

1) Use android frame work and iOS framework.
2) Or use a cross platform development library something like (AirPlay SDK for example).
3) Or there is other way else you prefer.

Please feel free to give me your suggestions.

Edit: I forgot to say, it'll be a game which require a lot of 2-D graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write your common code in C++, both platforms support it. for platform dependent code you can create one interface with two different implementation

Comment: Can I use it to build a game?

Comment: The problem is that the major inconsistencies between platforms are in the UI.  Having common "business logic" does little good in most cases.

Comment: @mohamede1945 are you asking if you can use C++ to build a game?

Comment: sorry for the late reply..
Yes, check out:
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nubee.coinpirates&feature=search_result
http://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/coin-pirates/id414430333?mt=8
is the example of games coded that way... a lot of game studios are building their own in-house engine this way as well..
It is similar to the way multiplatform games (PS3 & X360 esp) are written

Answer (score 1):

Appcelerator Titanium is a solution. You write your app in Javascript/CSS and it compiles to Android and iOS via shims.

http://www.appcelerator.com/

Comment: Can I use it to build a game?

Answer (score 1):

[PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) is also a good choice if you want to deploy to multiple platforms.

Comment: Can I use it to build a game?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the application, I'd take a strong look at HTML5 combined with something like jQuery Mobile.  Unless your application requires more of the sophisticated resources on the device, this cross platform approach may be appropriate

Comment: Can I use it to build a game?

Comment: Depends on what the game is :).  There are plenty of JavaScript only games

Comment: If you need to tie into things like the accelerometer, LED notification lights, vibration (device hardware) this approach probably will not be reasonable

Comment: Will require graphics and physics just like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_Ninja

Comment: I don't want anything except touches and gestures

Comment: Google made a playable version of Pacman using HTML5.  That's an example of its potential.  http://www.google.com/pacman/

Answer (score 1):

If it's a game you should consider [Shiva3D](http://www.stonetrip.com/) and [Unity](http://unity3d.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I always create two aplications, and i try to make them the most equal possible but using always all device functions needed.

Comment: Is it effective, what makes you do that?